# getting a users birthday mysql im confused with this code

Tags: mysql

Lets say you have a simple table that has a users date of birth as a date type.

i have this query here

```
select dob, 
    case dob
        when  DATE_FORMAT(dob,'%m-%d') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%m-%d') then 1
        else 0 end
        as ,  
    DATE_FORMAT(dob,'%m-%d') as test,
    DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%m-%d') as test2 
FROM users
```

i am getting wierd results like this

[image: Its seems to be doing different outputs]

Its seems to be doing different values saying that the DATE_FORMAT(dob,'%m-%d') equals 00-00 but in the cell it outputs correctly.

Comment: Remove the `dob` after the `case`.

Comment: @solarflare you should post your comment in the former of an answer and score some points! :-)